# what is communication channel security?

Tags: security

I have searched in google and didnt find any.

Comment: You will get far more helpful advice if you ask a more complete and coherent question - what is the context? what problem are you trying to solve? what platform are you using? are you talking about web security? SSL? TLS? VPN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Communication Channel Security

The communication channel used depends on different cases[3]

```
* Front end and application server uses RFC
* Application server and application server uses RFC
* SAP J2EE Engine and application server uses RFC
* SAP router and application server uses RFC
* Connection to database uses RFC
* Web browser and application server uses HTTP, HTTPS, and SOAP
```

hope that helps